# Issue using pip - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.parser'

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have no idea how to fix this issue. I know I have the html library installed (if I open a python shell and type import html it works) but I can not use pip to do anything because I get this error when I try to use it for any command. Any ideas?

```
PS C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts> pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "c:\users\emre balci\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\users\emre balci\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\users\emre balci\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\users\emre balci\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "c:\users\emre balci\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip-18.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "c:\users\emre balci\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip-18.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_internal\cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "c:\users\emre balci\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip-18.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_internal\index.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import unescape
  File "c:\users\emre balci\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip-18.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\distlib\compat.py", line 85, in <module>
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.parser'
```

C:\Users\Emre Balci>where python
C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe

C:\Users\Emre Balci>where pip
C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe

C:\Users\Emre Balci>echo %path%
C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36;C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

C:\Users\Emre Balci>python -m pip -version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    **import**(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip__init__.py", line 28, in 
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\subversion.py", line 9, in 
    from pip.index import Link
  File "C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 31, in 
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 39, in 
    from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 14, in 
    from .compat import sysconfig, detect_encoding, ZipFile
  File "C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\distlib\compat.py", line 85, in 
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'html.parser'

C:\Users\Emre Balci>python -m site

sys.path = [
    'C:\Users\Emre Balci',
    'C:\Apps\cygwin64\home\Emre Balci\code',
    'C:\Apps\cygwin64\home\Emre Balci\code\core',
    'C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python36.zip',
    'C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs',
    'C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib',
    'C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36',
    'C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages',
    'C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip-18.0-py3.6.egg',
]

USER_BASE: 'C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Roaming\Python' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: 'C:\Users\Emre Balci\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True

Comment: What are the outputs of `where python` and `where pip`? Or if it's not too long, show us your PATH.

Comment: added that output above

Comment: what happens if you try `python -m pip --version`?

Comment: same error as the first command added output above

Comment: What does `python -m site` output? There's something pretty fishy going on here. Did you uninstall Anaconda recently, by chance? Or anything like moving from Python2 to Python3?

Comment: I added output above. I have Python2 and Python3 installed. I had python2 first but needed Python3. I installed 3.7 and got this issue and then uninstalled and tried 3.6 and the issue still persisted. I don't have this issue with the Python2 installation.